# Bounds on Linear Unique Game value

Tags: probability, computer-science

Suppose we have a system of $N$ linear equations in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of the form $x_i - x_j = c_{ij}$ where the $x_i$ are variables and the $c_{ij}$ are constants.

Suppose that at most $M$ of these equations can be satisfied at once and that $M/N = \beta$

Now there is a game where there are two contestants, $P_1$ and $P_2$. $P_1$ and $P_2$ can collude but they cannot communicate once the game starts. The game selects an equation at random, and tells $P_1$ the index of the first variable $i$ and $P_2$ the index of the second variable $j$. $P_1$ and $P_2$ respond with values for $x_i$ and $x_j$ respectively, and they win if $x_i - x_j = c_{ij}$

There is an "obvious" fact that the best strategy wins with a probability of at most $\max\{4\beta, 1\} $, except I don't see why the $4\beta$ part is so obvious.

(The statement comes from http://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/icm-khot.pdf page 6)

Comment: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be any event.  Then $\max[4\beta, 1] \geq 1 \geq Pr[\mathcal{E}]$ (since a probability cannot exceed 1).  So this is indeed obvious.  Of course, I suspect there is a typo in your writeup.  Do you mean "min"?

Comment: I read through the link you gave...the writing was unclear to me. I could not tell how $n$ and $N$ related, and which one is scaling up when we evaluate "polynomial time."  Also, I could not decipher this sentence "The value of the game is the maximum over all prover strategies, the probability that the verifier accepts."  Futher, it does indeed seem that the author is claiming a probability of $\max[4\beta, 1]$, which means the author likely has typos (among other things).

Comment: I found your writeup to be more clear, except I did not understand the size of the $(x_1,x_2, \ldots)$ vector, and what exactly is meant by "at most $M$ of the equations can be satisfied" (does this assume you have a full vector?)

Comment: Ah yes, it would seem that I meant min because the max statement is obvious! Let me check about your other concerns

Comment: I think the large $N$ stays fixed and the little $n$ is scaling up. Polynomial time is a concept from computer science. If a problem is Polynomial time, it means the time a Turing machine would need to compute a solution is dominated by some polynomial function of the input size. The input size here is the length of some "reasonable" binary encoding of the problem.

Comment: The value of the game is the maximum probability that the verifier accepts. The maximization is carried out over the set of all possible prover strategies.

Comment: Yes you choose a full vector, meaning you assign a value to each variable and you see how many of the equations come out true. It's given that no matter how you choose the variables, no more than $M$ of the equations will be true.

Comment: The paper suggests $N$ is fixed, which makes no sense.  If $N=2$, there are only two equations:  $x_1-x_2 = c_{12}$ and $x_2-x_1=c_{21}$. The only way to solve both is if $c_{12} = -c_{21}$. There is nothing "non-polynomial" here, regardless of the size of small $n$.  Likewise, for $N=3$, there are at most 6 equations. The total number of vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ that uses entries in $\{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ is $n^3$ (indeed polynomial).  If $N$ is a positive integer that is not scaling, there are $n^N$ vectors, still polynomial in small $n$.